# Add to private HashMap<Integer, HashSet<exampleObject>> test in java

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I'm exploring hash set and hash map, I'm looking to add to this:

```
private HashMap<Integer, HashSet<exampleObject>> test;

test = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<exampleObject>>();
```

for example the exampleObject is made up from int, String, String,

I've tried (as well as other things)

```
test.put(1, exampleObject.add(new exampleObject(1,"a","b")));
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `test.computeIfAbsent(1, key -> new HashSet<>()).add(new ExampleObject(1, "a", "b")));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your add() method return boolean and can't be used in your example.
And you need to create a data structure HashSet.
For example:

```
private static HashMap<Integer, HashSet<exampleObject>> test = new HashMap<>();
private static HashSet<exampleObject> hashSet = new HashSet<>(); 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    hashSet.add(new exampleObject("key", "value")); // <-- returns boolean
    test.put(1, hashSet);
    for (exampleObject element : test.get(1)) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

P.S. exampleObject have 2 String fields here. And don't forget to override equals() and hashCode() in exampleObject for the correct output of the object to print.